# how to show html of div on loading data to popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-models, django-templates

javascript:

```
$('.follower_name').click(function () {              
      var id = $(this).attr('id');  
      var csrf_token = $("#csrf_token").val();
      $.ajax({ 
       data:{
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: ('{{csrf_token}}'),                          
            id:id,  
            edit_followup:true              
            },
      type:'POST',
      url: '/setting/edit_follower/',
      success: function(data) {    
      $('#add_form').show();
      $('#add_form').html(data);
     alert(data);
     }
    });
   });
```

html:

```
<div id="add_form"  style="display:none" class="edit_follow">
    <form id="form"  method="post" action="edit_follower/{{follower.id}}/"  onsubmit="return form_validate()">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h2> Follow-up details</h2>
        <br />
        <table  width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:100px;">First name:</td><td>{{ form.firstname}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:100px;">Last name:</td><td>{{ form.lastname}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email:</td><td>{{ form.email}}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <div style="width:180px;margin:20px 5px 0 10px" align="right">

            <button style="margin-right:10px;" type="button" class="close" name="cancel" class="forward backicon">                
            Cancel</button>   {% include "buttons/add.html" %}
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

views.py

```
def edit_follower(request):  
    if request.method == 'POST':
    """"""'
    return HttpResponse(form)
```

Now the popup is showing as below:

[image]

I want to show as below

[image]

I am loading the data from database to popup div.The problem is,
It just showing the form data alone and not the html of popup.Example it is not showing the buttons,"First name" but it is showing the text box with value of First name field.

Comment: My problem is the entire div is replaced by the form data instead of inserting the form data into form field,so my other html are missing.How to append the html along with form data.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try like this. P.S. I'm not the expert in this area :)

```
$('.follower_name').click(function () {              
  var id = $(this).attr('id');  
  var csrf_token = $("#csrf_token").val();
  $.ajax({ 
   data:{
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: ('{{csrf_token}}'),                          
        id:id,  
        edit_followup:true              
        },
  type:'POST',
  url: '/setting/edit_follower/',
  success: function(data) {    
  $('#add_form').show();
  $('#add_form').html(
    '<div id="add_form" style="display:none" class="edit_follow">' +
    '<form id="form"  method="post" action="edit_follower/{{follower.id}}/" onsubmit="return form_validate()">' + '{% csrf_token %}' +
    '<h2> Follow-up details</h2>' +
    '<br />' +
    '<table  width="100%">' +
        '<tr>' +
            '<td style="width:100px;">First name:</td><td>{{ form.firstname}}</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr>' +
            '<td style="width:100px;">Last name:</td><td>{{ form.lastname}}</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr>' +
            '<td>Email:</td><td>{{ form.email}}</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
     '</table>' +
     '<div style="width:180px;margin:20px 5px 0 10px" align="right">' +

     '<button style="margin-right:10px;" type="button" class="close" name="cancel" class="forward backicon">Cancel</button>' +  '{% include "buttons/add.html" %}' +
     '</div>' +
 '</form>' +
'</div>');

 alert(data);
 }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because of the below line...

```
$('#add_form').html(data);
```

This line will simply place the data as the HTML inside the div `add_form`.
So, whatever you had before inside that div will be replaced by data.

Comment: Could you please provide me a solution for this problem.

Comment: Ok,i am waiting for your answer.